# Record video with overlay pager android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, surfaceview

I am working on one of my app in android which have functionality to capture video with overlay view pager. I tried take snapshot of view of every moment and after that use frames to make video using opencv and ffmpeg plugin but still there is no success . I need solution that how can i achieve this thing .

Sorry for unclearness , i am new here.

Please guide me solution anyone .

[Here is what i want to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iI5d.png)

Comment: Hi Vikas, Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `ffmpeg -r 1/5 -start_number 2 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`?
I guess that's what you want.

I actually do this things with [Blender 3D software](http://blender.org) but It's a little bit technical.

Comment: Firstly thanx for reply . here i want to record pager view along with surface view. i think what you answer provided is making video from frame .

Comment: Sorry for that! So you need screen recorder. Im not pro in android programming but can this help? https://gist.github.com/scottgwald/7743453

Comment: Seems like it will only capture surface view . I want capture both surfaceview and pager together.